# E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages trying to install wine on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, software-installation, wine, focaltech

Recently I tried to install Wine, but I tried to install Jammy version by accident, and now, when I try this command

`sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging`

I get this output

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 7.6~jammy-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I solve it?
I don't get any errors with sudo apt update or sudo apt upgrade

```
sudo apt update

Ign:1 http://packages.linuxmint.com una InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                         
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Hit:4 http://packages.linuxmint.com una Release                                
Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/21.04/prod hirsute InRelease       
Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease      
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:11 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Hit:12 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:13 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

If I try to unhold all held packages I get this output

```
sudo apt-mark unhold $(apt-mark showhold)
E: No packages found
```

I've tried with these aptitude commands

```
sudo aptitude install winehq-staging
sudo aptitude -f install winehq-staging
```

but they don't seem to solve anything, the actions that aptitude do are just keep the packages at their current version.

I downloaded winehq-staging_7.6~focal-1_amd64.deb and I got this output

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all winehq-staging_7.6~focal-1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package winehq-staging.
(Reading database ... 378899 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack winehq-staging_7.6~focal-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking winehq-staging (7.6~focal-1) ...
dpkg: winehq-staging: dependency problems, but configuring anyway as you requested:
 winehq-staging depends on wine-staging (= 7.6~focal-1); however:
  Package wine-staging is not installed.

Setting up winehq-staging (7.6~focal-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24+linuxmint1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
```

but wine seems to still being unavailable.
I tried to remove the broken package using Synaptic Package Manager, the first try it was unable to remove it, then I did it again and the broken package seems to be already removed.
But I keep getting this output

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 5075 (synaptic)       
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 7.6~jammy-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and sudo apt update keeps showing

```
Hit:10 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease
```

I just got the git repository and build it with make and seems that that solved the problem. But I still having the https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease line.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: You need to remove the jammy line that you added to your sources.

Comment: How can I remove that jammy line?

Comment: Undo everything that you did and install the version of wine from the Ubuntu repos unless you have a specific need for the latest and greatest version.

Comment: How can I undo that? I do want to install the Focal version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` will open your sources list for editing. Delete the jammy line that you previously added. Save, exit, and rerun `sudo apt update`

Comment: `/etc/apt/sources.list` seems completely empty

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu ot Mint?  The lines with 'linuxmint' following ´sudo apt update` are most unusual.

Comment: Linux Mint, equivalent to Ubuntu 20.04 Focal

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the `.deb` file for `winehq-staging`

https://pkgs.org/download/winehq-staging

After downloading, run this

`sudo dpkg -i --force-all [package_name].deb`

This works for me

Comment: +1 because this is a valid solution.  However, OP is already having dependency issues. I'm not sure that installing the software from a `.deb` file is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

add universe repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

then update cache

```
sudo apt update
```

lastly

```
sudo apt install wine
```